# Creating a List of Objects in C# that use two classes

Tags: c#, list, object, getter-setter

I have a website with a table of rows. Each row has two columns of values. what I want to do is to store each row into own place in a list, and have user the ability to enter the value in the list and access each column value individually, i.e; not just making a string of the row. The final code will contain a for loop to loop through the rows and webscraping code, but for troubleshooting I omitted that and am just hardcoding the values. I began with 2 classes, one for the getter/setters for the individual class values and another to get/set that object. From there I created a method to set the values.

```
        public class Student
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
        }

        public class ListOfStudents
        {
            public Student student { get; set; }
        }

        public static ListOfStudents GetListOfStudents()
        {
            List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
            Student student = new Student
            {
                Name = "Mike",
                Address = "Main St"
            };            
            ListOfStudents listOfStudents = new ListOfStudents
            {
                students.Add(Student)
            };
            return listOfStudents;
        }
```

I'm getting this error "Cannot initialize type 'ListClass.ListOfStudents' with a collection initializer because it does not implement System.Collections.IEnumerable" Essentially I can't determine how to make the list of objects.

Comment: You probably mean to have `class ListOfStudents : List<Student>`, but there's not really any point to doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot use List

```
public class ListOfStudents
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

and other code:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
Student student = new Student
{
    Name = "Mike",
    Address = "Main St"
}; 
students.Add(Student);           
ListOfStudents listOfStudents = new ListOfStudents
{
    Students = students;
};
```

> Edit

But your code very wierd, pls say what you really want

Comment: Sorry about that. I want to add every row of a table to a list, and then nest the column values into the list so I can access each column value of a row individually.  An example would be, find row one and then access only the address in that row. I originally wrote code that stored the entire row into a string, but that was messy and needed to delimit the column values and whatnot. I assume there's a cleaner way.

Comment: if i got it right, you can with help foreach add all Student in List Student and then work with this list

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code you because **students** is not a **propertie** of ListOfStudents Without forgetting that the student propertie of ListOfStudents  suppose to be a list you can use the code below

```
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class ListOfStudents
    {
        public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }

    public static ListOfStudents GetListOfStudents()
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
        Student student = new Student
        {
            Name = "Mike",
            Address = "Main St"
        };
        students.Add(student);
        ListOfStudents listOfStudents = new ListOfStudents()
        {
            Students = students
        };
        return listOfStudents;
    }
```

As a .net developer in the current context I recommend to use what is called an **Indexer**

> ### Indexer :
>
> > An indexer is a special type of property that provides access to a class or structure in the same way as a table for its internal collection. This is the same as the property except that it has been defined with this keyword with square brackets and parameters.

**[source]** https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-indexer

Exemple of how to use an indexer in your context  :

```
 public class Student
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
 }

 public class ListOfStudents
 {
    public Student[] Students = new Student[100];

    public Student this[int index]
    {
        get { return Students[index]; }
        set { Students[index] = value; }
    }
 }
```